# Twig filter not available in Generator

Tags: symfony, twig, generator, symfony-2.6, twig-extension

When I call my custom filter it fail with:

```
  [Twig_Error_Syntax] Unknown "snake_case" filter in "controller/controller.php.twig" at line 86.
```

The service is registered:

```
services:
l91_sulu_backend.twig.converter.extension:
    class: L91\Sulu\Bundle\BackendBundle\Twig\ConverterTwigExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

It is listed under `container:debug`

The class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace L91\Sulu\Bundle\BackendBundle\Twig;

class ConverterTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('snake_case', [$this, 'snakeCaseFilter']),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $input
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function snakeCaseFilter($input)
    {
        return strrev($input); // just to test
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'l91_sulu_backend_converter';
    }
}
```

Also `twig:debug` list my `snake_case` filter.

The twig file is rendered by a Generator called by a symfony command.

And here the call of the filter

```
'{{ translatePrefix }}.{{ column|snake_case }}',
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it out as a Generator use its own TwigEnvironment you need to register all used extensions yourself.

```
/**
 * @return \Twig_Environment
 */
public function getTwigEnvironment()
{
    $twigEnvironment = parent::getTwigEnvironment();

    $twigEnvironment->addExtension(new ConverterTwigExtension());

    return $twigEnvironment;
}
```